# How to build this has_many relation through an has_one relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Please excuse my english if it's not perfect.

I want to be able to create a `theme` with one `subcategory` (and subcategory has one theme), and link this `theme` to multiple `categories`. I wish I could do `Theme.first.categories` or `Category.first.themes`.

In the themes table, I only save the name and the slug. In the subcategories table, I save the description, page title, etc. because each category will have themes with same name but different descriptions.

For example, I can have two categories like 'French to English' and 'Italian to Chinese'. These categories will both have a theme named 'sciences' but with a different description.

Currently, I can create a theme but only with one category. If I'm choosing two categories for instance, I got an error: `can't modify frozen Hash`.

**theme.rb:**

```
    class Theme < ApplicationRecord
      has_one(:subcategory, dependent: :destroy)
      has_many(:categories, through: :subcategory)

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategory
    end
```

**subcategory.rb:**

```
    class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to(:category)
      belongs_to(:theme)
    end
```

**category.rb:**

```
    class Category < ApplicationRecord
      has_many(:subcategories, dependent: :destroy)
      has_many(:themes, through: :subcategories)
    end
```

**schema.rb:**

```
    create_table "themes", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "name", null: false
      t.string "slug"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    create_table "subcategories", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.text "description"
      t.string "page_title"
      t.string "meta_description"
      t.string "h1_title"
      t.bigint "category_id"
      t.bigint "theme_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_subcategories_on_category_id"
      t.index ["theme_id"], name: "index_subcategories_on_theme_id"
    end

    create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "name", null: false
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.string "slug"
      t.text "description"
      t.string "page_title"
      t.string "meta_description"
      t.string "h1_title"
      t.string "source_language"
      t.string "target_language"
    end
```

**themes_controller.rb:**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

    module Admin
      class ThemesController < AdminController
        load_and_authorize_resource except: :update
        before_action(:load_categories, only: %i[new edit])
        before_action(:load_theme, only: :update)

        def index
          @themes = Theme.all.to_a
        end

        def new
          @theme.build_subcategory
        end

        def create
          @theme = Theme.new(theme_params)
          if @theme.save
            redirect_to(admin_themes_url, notice: 'Theme successfully created')
          else
            render(:new)
          end
        end

        def edit
        end

        def update
          if @theme.update(theme_params)
            redirect_to(admin_themes_url, notice: 'Theme successfully edited')
          else
            render(:edit)
          end
        end

        def destroy
          @theme.destroy
          redirect_to(admin_themes_url, notice: 'Theme successfully deleted')
        end

      private

        def theme_params
          params.require(:theme).permit(
            :id,
            :name,
            :slug,
            subcategory_attributes: %i[description h1_title page_title meta_description],
            category_ids: [],
          )
        end

        def load_categories
          @categories = Category.all.to_a
        end

        def load_theme
          @theme = Theme.find_by(slug: params[:id])
        end
      end
    end
```

**and my form:**

```
    = simple_form_for([:admin, @theme]) do |f|
      = f.input(:name, autofocus: true)
      = f.simple_fields_for :subcategory_attributes, @theme.subcategory do |s|
        = s.input(:h1_title)
        = s.input(:description)
        = s.input(:page_title)
        = s.input(:meta_description)
      = f.input(:category_ids, collection: @categories.map { |cat| [cat.name, cat.id] }, as: :check_boxes, wrapper: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes)
      = f.button(:submit , class: 'btn btn-primary')
```

**logs:**

```
0:39:39 server.1 | Started POST "/admin/themes" for ::1 at 2019-01-11 10:39:39 +0100
10:39:39 server.1 | Processing by Admin::ThemesController#create as HTML
10:39:39 server.1 |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6p2oxZvOlFJHYvAeYbkjjOrGGk8Y5GrnFOTBuQEmxTcMIhgfK32N2/ZGabLYmoW0pHiUaX6hVqb/EeuTgbr55g==", "theme"=>{"name"=>"rerezre", "subcategory_attributes"=>{"h1_title"=>"reez", "description"=>"rezer", "page_title"=>"rezrez", "meta_description"=>"rezerez"}, "category_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Créer un(e) Theme"}
10:39:39 server.1 |   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:93
10:39:39 server.1 |   Category Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ /Users/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ /Users/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ /Users/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
10:39:39 server.1 |   CACHE Category Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:18
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:18
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.1ms)  COMMIT
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:18
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |   Category Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE LOWER("categories"."name") = LOWER($1) AND "categories"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Français à anglais"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |   Category Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE LOWER("categories"."name") = LOWER($1) AND "categories"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Italien à chinois"], ["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |   Theme Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "themes" ("name", "slug", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "rerezre"], ["slug", "rerezre"], ["created_at", "2019-01-11 09:39:39.193694"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-11 09:39:39.193694"]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |   Subcategory Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "subcategories" ("description", "page_title", "meta_description", "h1_title", "category_id", "theme_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["description", "rezer"], ["page_title", "rezrez"], ["meta_description", "rezerez"], ["h1_title", "reez"], ["category_id", 2], ["theme_id", 24], ["created_at", "2019-01-11 09:39:39.196215"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-11 09:39:39.196215"]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |   Category Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE LOWER("categories"."name") = LOWER($1) AND "categories"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Français à anglais"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 |    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
10:39:39 server.1 |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19
10:39:39 server.1 | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
10:39:39 server.1 |
10:39:39 server.1 |
10:39:39 server.1 | can't modify frozen Hash excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'
10:39:39 server.1 |
10:39:39 server.1 | FrozenError (can't modify frozen Hash):
10:39:39 server.1 |
10:39:39 server.1 | app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

I know that there's a problem with the relations if I want to do what I want, but I don't know how to do it.

Please someone could help me?

Comment: Can we see what data you’re trying to submit when the error occurs, the code which it uses and a few lines of the error backtrack?

Comment: I tried the same schema but the record is not saved and I don't have any error, but maybe the problem is simply in my simple_form. I'm going to look for this

Comment: Yes @TomDunning, I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

There's a conceptual problem here.
Since `Theme` has a one-to-one relationship with `Subcategory`, which has a one-to-many relationship with `Category` the transitive relationship between `Theme` and `Category` cannot be many-to-many. For that to be possible `Theme` must have at least a one-to-many relationship with `Subcategory`.

In other words:
Every Theme has exactly one Subcategory, every Subcategory has exactly one Category, therefore every Theme has exactly one Category through Subcategory.
If you want a Theme to have more than one Category (through Subcategories) then you should allow a Theme to have many Subcategories.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I had at the beginning so the problem is with my form or controller and not with the relations :/

Comment: Maybe the relations problem is unrelated to the error you're seeing. But unless you revert to your earlier state, where a Topic was allowed to have more than one Category, you cannot expect to successfully create a Topic with more than one Category. If you then still see the error, I'd suggest to create a Topic with two Categories in the rails console and see if the error occurs there as well, to narrow down the source of the problem.

But first you need to fix your relationship specification.

Comment: I reverted my changes and, now, a Theme can have many categories, in the console. I don't understand what is the problem when I try to create a Theme with multiple categories in the view, I still have to search

Comment: Well, what is the difference between the parameters that you submit to the controller and the parameters that you used in the console? Remember that you cannot directly assign a Category to a Theme, you must assign Subcategories instead.